# Using visual studio graphics debugger OR nvidia nsight with steam games

Tags: visual-studio, 3d, directx, nsight, steam

I generally use Intel GPA to profile and analyze the rendering process of games on Steam. I wanted to explore Visual Studio's graphics debugger and Nvidia nSight, but I can't get them to "latch" onto the game's process.

This seems to be because of the way steam games are launched. Clicking on the game.exe launches a steam process that in turn launches the game. I don't know why Valve does it this way, but it prevents these tools from "hooking" onto the process and capturing frames.

I tried using the "steam_appid.txt" file to prevent this launch sequence (the steam API mentions this), but to no avail. Just to clarify - I don't have access to the source of these games; i'm just interested in rendering analysis.

Comment: Probably it's obvious, but I just want to remind. Many of the games on Steam nowadays use OpenGL for rendering. If you cannot capture any frames, it could mean that there is no DirectX frames at all. Nsight supports limited OpenGL debugging, but Visuals Studio's debugger don't.

Comment: Umm, not really. Most of the games are still DX on Windows. From a GL tools perspective, it's a pretty sad state.
Vogl, Renderdoc, GPA are all work-in-progress as far as GL support is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Nsight can support "latch" you mentioned. Please configure Nsight's User Settings:

- Launch external program: *$PATH_TO_YOUR_STEAM_EXE*
- Check the check box named "Application is a launcher" [**Here is the key**]
- Working directory: *$PATH_TO_YOUR_STEAM_WORK_DIR*

Also remember to uncheck the "Synchronize files" in Synchronization section.

After all configurations have been done, just launch as usual, you will see a Attach dialog box pop out when the steam really runs.

Just run the game from steam, and double click on the game's process in Nsight's Attach dialog box, then you will see the Nsight HUD in the game and every feature for graphic debug of Nsight should works as normal.

The key here is tell Nsight that your 'steam.exe' is just a launcher, and Nsight's dll should hook on the children process from steam.exe, which means "hook/attach on your need".

Thanks
An

Comment: Ah, so that's how I need to use it :) 
Thanks much!